# TClientDataSet : Mismatch in datapacket

Tags: delphi, datasnap, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm on Delphi 10.3. I use TClientdataset a lot in my applications, as a way to locally store small amount of information, usually less than 10000 rows.

Basically i create the table structure and save it on disk :

```
myClientDataSet.savetofile('c:\mydata.dat') ;
```

This is a great way to have a persistence mechanism without having to install any database. It works but i noticed that at some point i can't open the file anymore, because when i try to load :

```
myClientDataSet.loadfromfile('c:\mydata.dat');
```

I'll get this error :

```
Mismatch in datapacket.
```

When this happens, as far as i know the only fix is to delete the file and create a new one, loosing all data (or restoring a backup, if it exists). In some cases this issue will take years to happen, but always happen at some point.

What can i do to avoid this issue and if it already happened, is there a way to recover the data file with this error ?

Thanks

Comment: *"is there a way to recover the data"* Open the file with a text editor to see what's in it.

Comment: Does the error also occur after a reboot? I ask to discriminate two possible cause: the file is open by something else or the file content is corrupted. Other question: does the error occur after the file has been updated?

Comment: @Olivier It's a binary file , nothing to see.

Comment: @fpiette I can't really identify when the error occurs, the only thing i know is, overtime it will happen

Comment: You didn't answered the first part of the question: Does the error occurs after a reboot? I mean when the error occurred, instead of deleting the file, reboot the computer and check if the error still occurs.

Comment: @fpiette Just tried it, the reboot won't fix the problem.

Comment: OK, this eliminate the possibility that the file remains open. Now we have to find out if the file is corrupted. Do you have the possibility to create a new file, work with it until the error occur, recording everything you have done and save the file. Then recreate a new file, do EXACTLY the same operations until the error occurred in the first run. If the error occurs again at the same point, a bug in the software is likely to be the cause. If the error do not reproduce, quit the application and compare the saved file with the current. If they are the same, this is likely an external cause.

Comment: @fpiette Thanks for the insights, but AFTER the file is on 'Mismatch in datapacket' situtation, is there anything i could do to recover (even if partial) its data ?

Comment: No idea. As @Olivier said: Open the file with a text editor to see what's in it. Start by looking at a correct file.

Comment: *"is there anything i could do to recover (even if partial) its data"* Nobody knows what happened to your file, so we can't answer that. You could try with the XML format instead (I forgot that the default format was binary). It's more verbose, but in case of corruption, it's much easier to see what happened and recover some data.

Comment: You could also keep a backup (e.g. mydata.bak). If mydata.dat is corrupt and can't be loaded, you could warn the user and load the backup instead.